# How to create a reader that reads first N bytes once then the rest?

Tags: go

I want to read the *first N bytes* **once**, then I want to read the rest until **io.EOF**. What do you think about the following code? Is this the best possible way?

If the given reader (r) doesn't start with the **first** bytes, it should return an error. Otherwise, it should continue to read the rest **after a set of fixed bytes** (labeled as "first" in the code).

You can think of the *"first"* section as a magic format signature.

```golang
type reader struct {
    r    io.Reader
    first []byte
}

func (r *reader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    const first = "first"

    n, err = r.r.Read(b)
    if len(r.first) >= len(first) {
        return n, err
    }

    if l := len(first); n > l {
        b = b[:l]
    }
    r.first = append(r.first, b...)

    if len(r.first) >= len(first) {
        if !bytes.HasPrefix(r.first, []byte(first)) {
            err = errors.New("not first")
        }
    }
    return n, err
}
```

The source code is on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/4xzEQcaXYXc

Comment: Are you trying to read the first N bytes, and fail if those are different from r.first? What's the deal with the constant "first"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's just some fixed data that I need to read (from a stream) before I read the rest (again from the same stream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation looks more involved than necessary:

```golang
type reader struct {
    r      io.Reader
    first  []byte
    offset int
}

func (r *reader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = r.r.Read(b)
    for i := 0; r.offset < len(r.first) && i < n; r.offset++ {
        if r.first[r.offset] != b[i] {
            return n, errors.New("mismatch")
        }
        i++
    }
    return n, err
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, you didn't check for the "first" bytes section. You can think of the "first" bytes as a magic signature.

Comment: It is checking if stream starts with r.first bytes

Comment: BTW, who's immediately upvoting what you write :) Is it a bot or something?

Comment: I guess the first if check is unnecessary but good for optimization purposes. Yeah?

Comment: You're right. It is unnecessary. It won't optimize anything either. I fixed the answer.